# Powershell seems unable to download a file via Invoke Webrequest from telgram API

Tags: powershell, telegram

I'm wondering if anyone can help and I apologise profusely if this has been answered before. I have never worked with powershell or web api's for that matter but im trying to learn, anyway..

I have a telegram bot and i sent a txt file to it from my device, i was then given a filepath which I added to my URL and straight away chrome downloaded the file no problem, but for whatever reason powershell just displays (very briefly) "web request status, number of bytes processed 0" and then finished with no file added to the -outfile path.

I can copy and paste the url into any web browser and it instantly downloads the file but powershell doesnt.

this is the link https://api.telegram.org/file/bot1804391976:AAHY2CjkxmXIu0sJ7CvOWl6iwolZL6Qbyq0/documents/file_0.txt

and this is the powershell cmdlet i was trying..

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://api.telegram.org/file/bot1804391976:AAHY2CjkxmXIu0sJ7CvOWl6iwolZL6Qbyq0/documents/file_0.txt" -OutFile "c:/desktop"
```

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You should specify what type of file you will be outputting it to: `-OutFile "c:\temp\file.txt"`. I also would play it safe and wrap the url in single quotes instead: `Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://api.telegram.org/file/bot1804391976:AAHY2CjkxmXIu0sJ7CvOWl6iwolZL6Qbyq0/documents/file_0.txt' -OutFile "c:\desktop\file.txt"`. Also, you may run into trouble if you don't have a folder named *desktop* in your `C:\` root. Ensure it's there first, or point to another folder.

Comment: Thank you so much! wrapping in single quotes fixed my issue straight away! I was under the impression that there wasnt a difference between them when using powershell.. 

Thank you again!